# YUI Datatable - merging multiple columns into one column

Tags: xml, datatable, yui

I'd like to merge/concatenate the contents of two columns and display them in one column.

I was hoping it would be as easy as ["column 1" + "Column2"] inside the responseSchema. So from my code below, I want to do something like ["item-name" + "condition", "color", "keep"].
Here's the relevant part of my current datatable code...

```
            var myColumnDefs = [
            {key:"item-name", sortable:true, resizeable:true, width:100},
            {key:"condition", sortable:true, resizeable:true},
            {key:"color", sortable:true, resizeable:true},
            {key:"keep", sortable:true, resizeable:true},
        ];

        var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource("http://192.168.2.5:3000/items.xml");
        myDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_XML;
        myDataSource.responseSchema = {
            resultNode: "item",
            fields: ["item-name", "condition", "color", "keep"]
        };

        var myDataTable = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable("dt-container",
                myColumnDefs, myDataSource);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the

```
      {key:"item-name", sortable:true, resizeable:true, width:100},
```

line to

```
      {key:"item-name", sortable:true, resizeable:true, width:100, 
        formatter: function (el, oRecord, oColumn, oData) {
          var condition = oRecord.getData('condition');
          el.innerHTML += '&nbsp;' + condition;
        }
      },
```

then removing the

```
     {key:"condition", sortable:true, resizeable:true},
```

line.

Comment: This was a step in the right direction thanks, wish I had my final code here to post...cheers.